# Finding the highest average in a 2D List

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

one is 30 different movies (movie_names) and the other one is ratings (all_ratings) for the movies. In the rating list, I have 5 ratings provided by five different people as a single list. And I am trying to find the highest rated movies, the movies that have the highest average rating among all people. I know that I didn't take the average of the list but From the rating list I know that that there are two movies with a total rating of 25. So I tried to do the following:

```
highestrated = []
for i in range(30):
    totals.append(0)

for j in range(30):
    ch = 0
    for i in range(5):
        if all_ratings[i-1][j-1] == 0:
            ch = 1
    if ch == 0:
        for i in range(5):
            highestrated[j-1] = highestrated[j-1] + all_ratings[i-1][j-1]

for i in range(30):
    if highestrated[i-1] == 25:
        print("the highest rated movies are ",
              movie_names[i-1], highestrated[i-1])
```

However, I get this error

```
highestrated[j-1]=highestrated[j-1] + all_ratings[i-1][j-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Changing `totals.append(0)`to `highestrated.append(0)`  solved my problem!

Comment: `highestrated` starts out empty. Did you mean to initialize it?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: Try `highestrated = [0] * 30`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! How can I submit this question as solved?

Comment: Note you wrote `totals.append(0)` not `highestrated.append(0)`

Comment: Oh i see my mistake now! I copied the code from calculating an another value and I forgot to change the list name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clean example of what you're trying, which might help you out...

Say you start with a structure like this:

```py
ratings_lists = {
    "HarryPotter": [4,5,3,5,2],
    "LordOfTheRings": [5,5,5,4,3,6],
    ...
}
```

To get the averages you could do:

```py
ratings_average = {
    movie: sum(ratings) / len(ratings)
    for movie, ratings in ratings_lists.items()
}
```

To get the highest ratings we'll sort the dictionary:

```py
sorted_ratings_average {
    movie: rating
    for movie, rating in sorted(
        ratings_average.items(), 
        # This is a tuple of movie name and rating
        key=lambda rating_pair: rating_pair[1],
        # Reverse to get the highest on top
        reverse=True,
    )
}
```

Now print out the first five!

```
for movie, rating in sorted_ratings_average.items()[:5]:
    print(f"{movie}: {rating}")
```

Comment: Great! I am wondering how would you do it if the there were two lists  
`rating_lists=[4,5,3,5,2],[5,5,5,4,3,]` and 
`movie_names=["HarryPotter","Lord of The Rings","Cars","Baywatch","Jumanji"]`

Comment: @dojomaker You could create a dict by zipping the lists together in order to make a dict (as long as they have the same length): `ratings_dict = dict(zip(movie_names, rating_lists))`